# Reversing 2 columns in an excel sheet with one column having a single variable and the other column having a list using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I have 2 columns in an excel sheet with columns and values below

| Asset Ids | FADEL Ids |
| --- | --- |
| fcb03 | 12500,12502 |
| f813a | 4062 |
| d79ca | 16145 |
| fa632 | 6698 |
| 9c7cd | 4062, 6698 |
| 4d787 | 18933 |
| 5569a | 4062,6698 |
| 2cd98 | 16145 |
| 5d58d | 9965 |
| 52b30 | 12500,12502 |

I want an excel sheet with the below output

| Asset Ids | FADEL Ids |
| --- | --- |
| fcb03,52b30 | 12500 |
| fcb03,52b30 | 12502 |
| f813a,9c7cd,5569a | 4062 |
| d79ca,2cd98 | 16145 |
| fa632,9c7cd,5569a | 6698 |
| 4d787 | 18933 |
| 5d5bd | 9965 |

I want the answer through a python code. I tried implementing this through pandas dataframe and I am struck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df`, the input DataFrame, you can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (df
 .assign(**{'FADEL Ids': df['FADEL Ids'].str.split(',')})
 .explode('FADEL Ids')
 .groupby('FADEL Ids', as_index=False)
 ['Asset Ids'].agg(','.join)
)

print(out)
```

output:

```
  FADEL Ids          Asset Ids
0      6698              9c7cd
1     12500        fcb03,52b30
2     12502        fcb03,52b30
3     16145        d79ca,2cd98
4     18933              4d787
5      4062  f813a,9c7cd,5569a
6      6698        fa632,5569a
7      9965              5d58d
```

Comment: What do the double ** mean? I've seen this before, but don't know what it does

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn this is parameter expansion, I used it here as `assign(FADEL Ids=...)` would be invalid due to the space

Comment: can you please explain me what is df.assign etc

Comment: @Venkatesh `df.assign(x=y)` is the same as doing `df['x'] = y`, except this does it on a copy rather than modifying the original object

Comment: can you please share me the full code for it from reading the excel file and to write back in another excel file

Answer (score 0):

We could try with `get_dummies` with `dot`

```
s = df.set_index('Asset Ids')['FADEL Ids'].str.get_dummies(',')
out = s.T.dot(s.index+',').str[:-1].reset_index()
out
Out[130]: 
   index                  0
0  12500        fcb03,52b30
1  12502        fcb03,52b30
2  16145        d79ca,2cd98
3  18933              4d787
4   4062  f813a,9c7cd,5569a
5   6698  fa632,9c7cd,5569a
6   9965              5d58d
```

Comment: can you please upload the full code for it from reading the dataframe to writing the output in an excel file ?